# Dúvidas sobre SendMessage e PostMessage

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

Comecei a estudar os métodos de `SendMessage` e `PostMessage` do `User32.dll` e me veio algumas dúvidas. Vou colocar abaixo o código que eu testei e logo em seguida as perguntas, se alguém puder me ajudar.

```
            [DllImport("USER32.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
            public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName,
                                                                     string lpWindowName);

            [DllImport("USER32.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
            public extern static int SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, uint msg, uint wParam, uint lParam);
            [DllImport("USER32.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
            public extern static int PostMessage(IntPtr hwnd, uint msg, uint wParam, uint lParam);

        void FechaNotepad()
            {
                IntPtr handle = FindWindow("Notepad", "Sem título - Bloco de Notas");

                const int WM_QUIT = 0x0012;
                const int WM_CLOSE = 0x0010;
                const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
                const int WM_KEYUP = 0x101;
                const int WM_COMMAND = 0x111;
                const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x201;
                const int WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x202;
                const int WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x203;
                const int WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x204;
                const int WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x205;
                const int WM_RBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x206;

                SendMessage(handle, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
                SendMessage(handle, WM_QUIT, 0, 0);
                PostMessage(handle, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
                PostMessage(handle, WM_QUIT, 0, 0);
            }
```

**Dúvidas**

Para que eu realmente execute os comandos no processo encontrado, eu tenho que executar um `SendMessage()` e logo em seguida um `PostMessage()`? Não funciona apenas dando um `PostMessage()`?

Onde encontro endereços das mensagens que podem ser enviadas, como por exemplo, enviar a mensagem para pressionar a tecla `F1` do teclado?

Comment: Sim, funciona apenas com o PostMessage(), porém você deve analisar sua necessidade, e para isso você pode verificar a diferença entre ambas.
A função **SendMessage** é sincrona, e a função **PostMessage** é assíncrona. Aqui tem um tutorial onde você poderá avaliar essa diferença: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/SendMessage.htm O endereço de mensagem você pode encontrar na documentação da winapi.h, no caso da tecla F1 = 0x70, como voce pode ver aqui: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes

Comment: Formule seu comentário como resposta para que eu possa escolhe-la após os testes realizados amigo.

Answer (score 0):

Sim, funciona apenas com o PostMessage(), porém você deve analisar sua necessidade, e para isso você pode verificar a diferença entre ambas. A função SendMessage é sincrona, e a função PostMessage é assíncrona.

O endereço das mensagens (contantes) estou listando abaixo

```
     // Button message
     const int BM_GETCHECK = 0x00F0;
     const int BM_GETSTATE = 0x00F2;
     const int BM_SETSTATE = 0x00F3;
    // const int BM_CLICK = 0xF0F5;
     const int BM_CLICK = 0x00F5;

    // Combobox
     const int CB_GETCURSEL = 0x0147;
     const int CB_GETLBTEXT = 0x0148;
     const int CB_GETLBTEXTLEN = 0x0149;
     const int CB_SHOWDROPDOWN = 0x014F;
     const int CB_GETDROPPEDSTATE = 0x0157;

    // Date/Time picker
     const int DTM_GETSYSTEMTIME = 0x1001;
     const int DTM_SETSYSTEMTIME = 0x1002;
     const int DTM_GETMONTHCAL = 0x1008;

    // Editbox messages
     const int EM_GETSEL = 0x00B0;
     const int EM_SETSEL = 0x00B1;
     const int EM_GETRECT = 0x00B2;
     const int EM_LINESCROLL = 0x00B6;
     const int EM_GETLINECOUNT = 0x00BA;
     const int EM_LINEINDEX = 0x00BB;
     const int EM_LINEFROMCHAR = 0x00C9;
     const int EM_GETFIRSTVISIBLELINE = 0x00CE;
     const int EM_GETLIMITTEXT = 0x00D5;
     const int EM_POSFROMCHAR = 0x00D6;
     const int EM_CHARFROMPOS = 0x00D7;

    // SysHeader
     const int HDM_FIRST = 0x1200;
     const int HDM_GETITEMCOUNT = HDM_FIRST + 0;
     const int HDM_HITTEST = HDM_FIRST + 6;
     const int HDM_GETITEMRECT = HDM_FIRST + 7;
     const int HDM_GETITEMW = HDM_FIRST + 11;
     const int HDM_ORDERTOINDEX = HDM_FIRST + 15;
     const int HDM_GETITEMDROPDOWNRECT = HDM_FIRST + 25;
     const int HDM_GETFOCUSEDITEM = HDM_FIRST + 27;

    // Listbox messages
     const int LB_ERR = -1;
     const int LB_SETSEL = 0x0185;
     const int LB_SETCURSEL = 0x0186;
     const int LB_GETSEL = 0x0187;
     const int LB_GETCURSEL = 0x0188;
     const int LB_GETTEXT = 0x0189;
     const int LB_GETTEXTLEN = 0x018A;
     const int LB_GETCOUNT = 0x018B;
     const int LB_GETSELCOUNT = 0x0190;
     const int LB_SETTOPINDEX = 0x0197;
     const int LB_GETITEMRECT = 0x0198;
     const int LB_GETITEMDATA = 0x0199;
     const int LB_SETCARETINDEX = 0x019E;
     const int LB_GETCARETINDEX = 0x019F;
     const int LB_ITEMFROMPOINT = 0x01A9;

    // Listbox notification message
     const int LBN_SELCHANGE = 1;

    // List-view messages
     const int LVM_FIRST = 0x1000;
     const int LVM_GETITEMCOUNT = LVM_FIRST + 4;
     const int LVM_GETNEXTITEM = LVM_FIRST + 12;
     const int LVM_GETITEMRECT = LVM_FIRST + 14;
     const int LVM_GETITEMPOSITION = LVM_FIRST + 16;
     const int LVM_HITTEST = (LVM_FIRST + 18);
     const int LVM_ENSUREVISIBLE = LVM_FIRST + 19;
     const int LVM_SCROLL = LVM_FIRST + 20;
     const int LVM_GETHEADER = LVM_FIRST + 31;
     const int LVM_GETITEMSTATE = LVM_FIRST + 44;
     const int LVM_SETITEMSTATE = LVM_FIRST + 43;
     const int LVM_GETEXTENDEDLISTVIEWSTYLE = LVM_FIRST + 55;
     const int LVM_GETSUBITEMRECT = LVM_FIRST + 56;
     const int LVM_SUBITEMHITTEST = LVM_FIRST + 57;
     const int LVM_APPROXIMATEVIEWRECT = LVM_FIRST + 64;
     const int LVM_GETITEMW = LVM_FIRST + 75;
     const int LVM_GETTOOLTIPS = LVM_FIRST + 78;
     const int LVM_GETFOCUSEDGROUP = LVM_FIRST + 93;
     const int LVM_GETGROUPRECT = LVM_FIRST + 98; 
     const int LVM_EDITLABEL = LVM_FIRST + 118;
     const int LVM_GETVIEW = LVM_FIRST + 143;
     const int LVM_SETVIEW = LVM_FIRST + 142;
     const int LVM_SETGROUPINFO = LVM_FIRST + 147;
     const int LVM_GETGROUPINFO = LVM_FIRST + 149;
     const int LVM_GETGROUPINFOBYINDEX = LVM_FIRST + 153;
     const int LVM_GETGROUPMETRICS = LVM_FIRST + 156;
     const int LVM_HASGROUP = LVM_FIRST + 161;
     const int LVM_ISGROUPVIEWENABLED = LVM_FIRST + 175;
     const int LVM_GETFOCUSEDCOLUMN = LVM_FIRST + 186;

     const int LVM_GETEMPTYTEXT = LVM_FIRST + 204;
     const int LVM_GETFOOTERRECT = LVM_FIRST + 205;
     const int LVM_GETFOOTERINFO = LVM_FIRST + 206;
     const int LVM_GETFOOTERITEMRECT = LVM_FIRST + 207;
     const int LVM_GETFOOTERITEM = LVM_FIRST + 208;
     const int LVM_GETITEMINDEXRECT = LVM_FIRST + 209;
     const int LVM_SETITEMINDEXSTATE = LVM_FIRST + 210;
     const int LVM_GETNEXTITEMINDEX = LVM_FIRST + 211;

    // calendar control specific constants taken from commctrl.h
    // commctrl MONTHCAL CONTROL win messages
     const int MCM_FIRST = 0x1000;
     const int MCM_GETCURSEL = (MCM_FIRST + 1);
     const int MCM_SETCURSEL = (MCM_FIRST + 2);
     const int MCM_GETMAXSELCOUNT = (MCM_FIRST + 3);
     const int MCM_GETSELRANGE = (MCM_FIRST + 5);
     const int MCM_SETSELRANGE = (MCM_FIRST + 6);
     const int MCM_GETMONTHRANGE = (MCM_FIRST + 7);
     const int MCM_GETMINREQRECT = (MCM_FIRST + 9);
     const int MCM_GETTODAY = (MCM_FIRST + 13);
     const int MCM_HITTEST = (MCM_FIRST + 14);
     const int MCM_GETFIRSTDAYOFWEEK = (MCM_FIRST + 16);
     const int MCM_GETRANGE = (MCM_FIRST + 17);
     const int MCM_SETMONTHDELTA = (MCM_FIRST + 20);
     const int MCM_GETMAXTODAYWIDTH = (MCM_FIRST + 21);
     const int MCM_GETCURRENTVIEW = (MCM_FIRST + 22);
     const int MCM_GETCALENDARCOUNT = (MCM_FIRST + 23);
     const int MCM_GETCALENDARGRIDINFO = (MCM_FIRST + 24);

    // PAGER CONTROL from commctrl.h 
     const int PGM_FIRST = 0x1400;
     const int PGM_SETCHILD = (PGM_FIRST + 1);
     const int PGM_RECALCSIZE = (PGM_FIRST + 2);
     const int PGM_FORWARDMOUSE = (PGM_FIRST + 3);
     const int PGM_SETBKCOLOR = (PGM_FIRST + 4);
     const int PGM_GETBKCOLOR = (PGM_FIRST + 5);
     const int PGM_SETBORDER = (PGM_FIRST + 6);
     const int PGM_GETBORDER = (PGM_FIRST + 7);
     const int PGM_SETPOS = (PGM_FIRST + 8);
     const int PGM_GETPOS = (PGM_FIRST + 9);
     const int PGM_SETBUTTONSIZE = (PGM_FIRST + 10);
     const int PGM_GETBUTTONSIZE = (PGM_FIRST + 11);
     const int PGM_GETBUTTONSTATE = (PGM_FIRST + 12);

    // SysTabControl32
     const int TCM_FIRST = 0x1300;
     const int TCM_GETITEMCOUNT = TCM_FIRST + 4;
     const int TCM_GETITEMRECT = TCM_FIRST + 10;
     const int TCM_GETCURSEL = TCM_FIRST + 11;
     const int TCM_SETCURSEL = TCM_FIRST + 12;
     const int TCM_HITTEST = TCM_FIRST + 13;
     const int TCM_GETTOOLTIPS = TCM_FIRST + 45;
     const int TCM_GETCURFOCUS = TCM_FIRST + 47;
     const int TCM_SETCURFOCUS = TCM_FIRST + 48;
     const int TCM_DESELECTALL = TCM_FIRST + 50;
     const int TCM_GETITEMW = TCM_FIRST + 60;

    // TreeView 
     const int TV_FIRST = 0x1100;
     const int TVM_EXPAND = (TV_FIRST + 2);
     const int TVM_GETITEMRECT = (TV_FIRST + 4);
     const int TVM_GETCOUNT = (TV_FIRST + 5);
     const int TVM_GETNEXTITEM = (TV_FIRST + 10);
     const int TVM_SELECTITEM = (TV_FIRST + 11);
     const int TVM_HITTEST = (TV_FIRST + 17);
     const int TVM_ENSUREVISIBLE = (TV_FIRST + 20);
     const int TVM_ENDEDITLABELNOW = (TV_FIRST + 22);
     const int TVM_GETTOOLTIPS = (TV_FIRST + 25);
     const int TVM_GETITEMSTATE = (TV_FIRST + 39);
     const int TVM_MAPACCIDTOHTREEITEM = (TV_FIRST + 42);
     const int TVM_MAPHTREEITEMTOACCID = (TV_FIRST + 43);
     const int TVM_GETITEMW = (TV_FIRST + 62);
     const int TVM_SETITEMW = (TV_FIRST + 63);
     const int TVM_EDITLABELW = (TV_FIRST + 65);

    // Window
     const int WM_SETTEXT = 0x000C;
     const int WM_GETTEXT = 0x000D;
     const int WM_GETTEXTLENGTH = 0x000E;
     const int WM_QUIT = 0x0012;
     const int WM_GETFONT = 0x0031;
     const int WM_GETOBJECT = 0x003D;
     const int WM_NCHITTEST = 0x0084;
     const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
     const int WM_KEYUP = 0x0101;
     const int WM_COMMAND = 0x0111;
     const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
     const int WM_HSCROLL = 0x0114;
     const int WM_VSCROLL = 0x0115;
     const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;
     const int WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202;
     const int WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x0204;
     const int WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x0205;
     const int WM_MDITILE = 0x0226;
     const int WM_MDICASCADE = 0x0227;
     const int WM_HOTKEY = 0x0312;
     const int WM_GETTITLEBARINFOEX = 0x033F;
     const int WM_USER = 0x0400;

    // Dialog Codes
     const int WM_GETDLGCODE = 0x0087;
     const int DLGC_STATIC = 0x0100;

    // Slider
     const int TBM_GETPOS = WM_USER;
     const int TBM_GETRANGEMIN = WM_USER + 1;
     const int TBM_GETRANGEMAX = WM_USER + 2;
     const int TBM_SETPOS = WM_USER + 5;
     const int TBM_GETPAGESIZE = WM_USER + 22;
     const int TBM_GETLINESIZE = WM_USER + 24;
     const int TBM_GETTHUMBRECT = WM_USER + 25;
     const int TBM_GETCHANNELRECT = WM_USER + 26;
     const int TBM_GETTOOLTIPS = WM_USER + 30;

    // Progress Bar
     const int PBM_GETRANGE = (WM_USER + 7);
     const int PBM_GETPOS = (WM_USER + 8);

    // Status Bar
     const int SB_GETPARTS = (WM_USER + 6);
     const int SB_GETRECT = (WM_USER + 10);
     const int SB_GETTEXTLENGTHW = (WM_USER + 12);
     const int SB_GETTEXTW = (WM_USER + 13);

    // Rebar
     const int RB_HITTEST = WM_USER + 8;
     const int RB_GETRECT = WM_USER + 9;
     const int RB_GETBANDCOUNT = WM_USER + 12;
     const int RB_GETTOOLTIPS = WM_USER + 17;
     const int RB_GETBANDINFOA = WM_USER + 29;
     const int RB_PUSHCHEVRON = WM_USER + 43;

    // ToolBar
     const int TB_PRESSBUTTON = WM_USER + 3;
     const int TB_ISBUTTONENABLED = WM_USER + 9;
     const int TB_ISBUTTONCHECKED = WM_USER + 10;
     const int TB_ISBUTTONHIDDEN = WM_USER + 12;
     const int TB_GETBUTTON = WM_USER + 23;
     const int TB_BUTTONCOUNT = WM_USER + 24;
     const int TB_GETITEMRECT = WM_USER + 29;
     const int TB_GETTOOLTIPS = WM_USER + 35;
     const int TB_GETIMAGELIST = WM_USER + 49;
     const int TB_GETHOTITEM = WM_USER + 71;
     const int TB_SETHOTITEM = WM_USER + 72;
     const int TB_GETBUTTONTEXT = WM_USER + 75;
     const int TB_GETEXTENDEDSTYLE = WM_USER + 85;

    // Tooltip
     const int TTM_GETTOOLINFO = (WM_USER + 53);
     const int TTM_HITTEST = (WM_USER + 55);
     const int TTM_GETTEXT = (WM_USER + 56);
     const int TTM_GETCURRENTTOOL = (WM_USER + 59);

    // IPAddress
     const int IPM_SETADDRESS = (WM_USER + 101);

    //  SpinControl
     const int UDM_GETRANGE = (WM_USER + 102);
     const int UDM_SETPOS = (WM_USER + 103);
     const int UDM_GETPOS = (WM_USER + 104);
     const int UDM_GETBUDDY = (WM_USER + 106);

    // Hyperlink
     const int LM_FIRST = (WM_USER + 0x300);
     const int LM_HITTEST = LM_FIRST;
     const int LM_GETIDEALHEIGHT = (LM_FIRST + 1);
     const int LM_SETITEM = (LM_FIRST + 2);
     const int LM_GETITEM = (LM_FIRST + 3);


    // Button styles
     const int BS_PUSHBUTTON = 0x00000000;
     const int BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON = 0x00000001;
     const int BS_CHECKBOX = 0x00000002;
     const int BS_AUTOCHECKBOX = 0x00000003;
     const int BS_RADIOBUTTON = 0x00000004;
     const int BS_3STATE = 0x00000005;
     const int BS_AUTO3STATE = 0x00000006;
     const int BS_GROUPBOX = 0x00000007;
     const int BS_USERBUTTON = 0x00000008;
     const int BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON = 0x00000009;
     const int BS_PUSHBOX = 0x0000000A;
     const int BS_OWNERDRAW = 0x0000000B;
     const int BS_SPLITBUTTON = 0x0000000C;
     const int BS_TYPEMASK = 0x0000000F;

    // Date/Time picker styles
     const int DTS_UPDOWN = 0x0001;
     const int DTS_SHOWNONE = 0x0002;
    // DTS_TIMEFORMAT is wrongly defined in the common control include file with a value of 9
    // TIME_FORMAT + DTS_UPDOWN. 
     const int DTS_TIMEFORMAT = 0x0009;
    // Removes the UPDOWN bit. Use this const to check for TIMEFORMAT
     const int DTS_TIMEFORMATONLY = DTS_TIMEFORMAT & ~DTS_UPDOWN;

    // Dialogbox Styles
     const int DS_CONTROL = 0x00000400;

    // Editbox styles
     const int ES_LEFT = 0x0000;
     const int ES_CENTER = 0x0001;
     const int ES_RIGHT = 0x0002;
     const int ES_MULTILINE = 0x0004;
     const int ES_UPPERCASE = 0x0008;
     const int ES_LOWERCASE = 0x0010;
     const int ES_PASSWORD = 0x0020;
     const int ES_AUTOHSCROLL = 0x0080;
     const int ES_READONLY = 0x0800;
     const int ES_NUMBER = 0x2000;

    // Listbox styles
     const int LBS_NOTIFY = 0x0001;
     const int LBS_SORT = 0x0002;
     const int LBS_MULTIPLESEL = 0x0008;
     const int LBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED = 0x0010;
     const int LBS_WANTKEYBOARDINPUT = 0x0400;
     const int LBS_EXTENDEDSEL = 0x0800;
     const int LBS_COMBOBOX = 0x8000;

    // Listview styles
     const int LVS_REPORT = 0x0001;
     const int LVS_LIST = 0x0003;
     const int LVS_TYPEMASK = 0x0003;
     const int LVS_SINGLESEL = 0x0004;
     const int LVS_AUTOARRANGE = 0x0100;
     const int LVS_EDITLABELS = 0x0200;
     const int LVS_NOSCROLL = 0x2000;
     const int LVS_NOCOLUMNHEADER = 0x4000;

    // Listview extended styles
     const int LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES = 0x4;
     const int LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT = 0x00000020;
     const int LVS_EX_ONECLICKACTIVATE = 0x00000040;
     const int LVS_EX_TWOCLICKACTIVATE = 0x00000080;
     const int LVS_EX_UNDERLINEHOT = 0x00000800;
     const int LVS_EX_UNDERLINECOLD = 0x00001000;
     const int LVS_EX_JUSTIFYCOLUMNS = 0x00200000; // Icons are lined up in columns that use up the whole view area

    // Listview item states
     const int LVIS_FOCUSED = 0x0001;
     const int LVIS_SELECTED = 0x0002;
     const int LVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK = 0xFFFF;

    // commctrl MONTHCAL CONTROL style constants
     const int MCS_DAYSTATE = 0x0001;
     const int MCS_MULTISELECT = 0x0002;
     const int MCS_WEEKNUMBERS = 0x0004;
     const int MCS_NOTODAYCIRCLE = 0x0008;
     const int MCS_NOTODAY = 0x0010;

    // PAGER CONTROL styles from commctrl.h
     const int PGS_VERT = 0x00000000;
     const int PGS_HORZ = 0x00000001;

    // Scrollbar style
     const int SBS_HORZ = 0x0000;
     const int SBS_VERT = 0x0001;

    // Slider style
     const int TBS_VERT = 0x0002;
     const int TBS_REVERSED = 0x0200;

    // Static styles
     const int SS_LEFT = 0x00000000;
     const int SS_CENTER = 0x00000001;
     const int SS_RIGHT = 0x00000002;
     const int SS_ICON = 0x00000003;
     const int SS_BLACKRECT = 0x00000004;
     const int SS_GRAYRECT = 0x00000005;
     const int SS_WHITERECT = 0x00000006;
     const int SS_BLACKFRAME = 0x00000007;
     const int SS_GRAYFRAME = 0x00000008;
     const int SS_WHITEFRAME = 0x00000009;
     const int SS_USERITEM = 0x0000000A;
     const int SS_SIMPLE = 0x0000000B;
     const int SS_LEFTNOWORDWRAP = 0x0000000C;
     const int SS_OWNERDRAW = 0x0000000D;
     const int SS_BITMAP = 0x0000000E;
     const int SS_ENHMETAFILE = 0x0000000F;
     const int SS_ETCHEDHORZ = 0x00000010;
     const int SS_ETCHEDVERT = 0x00000011;
     const int SS_ETCHEDFRAME = 0x00000012;
     const int SS_TYPEMASK = 0x0000001F;

    // SysHeader32 styles
    // const int HDS_HORZ = 0x0000;
     const int HDS_VERT = 0x0001;

    // Toolbar styles
     const int TBSTYLE_EX_DRAWDDARROWS = 0x00000001;

    // Toolbar button styles
     const byte BTNS_SEP       = 0x0001;
     const byte BTNS_CHECK     = 0x0002;
     const byte BTNS_GROUP     = 0x0004;
     const byte BTNS_DROPDOWN  = 0x0008;

    // Image list constants
     const int I_IMAGENONE = -2;

    // Window styles
     const int WS_OVERLAPPED    = 0x00000000;
     const int WS_TABSTOP       = 0x00010000;
     const int WS_MAXIMIZEBOX   = 0x00010000;
     const int WS_GROUP         = 0x00020000;
     const int WS_MINIMIZEBOX   = 0x00020000;
     const int WS_SYSMENU       = 0x00080000;
     const int WS_HSCROLL       = 0x00100000;
     const int WS_VSCROLL       = 0x00200000;
     const int WS_BORDER        = 0x00800000;
     const int WS_CAPTION       = 0x00C00000;
     const int WS_MAXIMIZE      = 0x01000000;
     const int WS_DISABLED      = 0x08000000; 
     const int WS_VISIBLE       = 0x10000000;
     const int WS_MINIMIZE      = 0x20000000;
     const int WS_CHILD         = 0x40000000;
     const int WS_POPUP         = unchecked((int)0x80000000);

    // Window extended sytles
     const int WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME  = 0x00000001;
     const int WS_EX_MDICHILD       = 0x00000040;
     const int WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW     = 0x00000080;
     const int WS_EX_CONTEXTHELP    = 0x00000400;
     const int WS_EX_RTLREADING     = 0x00002000;
     const int WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT  = 0x00010000;
     const int WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL      = 0x00400000; // Right to left mirroring

    // Button states
     const int BST_UNCHECKED = 0x0000;
     const int BST_CHECKED = 0x0001;
     const int BST_INDETERMINATE = 0x0002;
     const int BST_PUSHED = 0x0004;
     const int BST_FOCUS = 0x0008;

    //GetDeviceCaps()
     const int LOGPIXELSX = 88;
     const int LOGPIXELSY = 90;

    // GetWindow()
     const int GW_HWNDFIRST = 0;
     const int GW_HWNDLAST = 1;
     const int GW_HWNDNEXT = 2;
     const int GW_HWNDPREV = 3;
     const int GW_OWNER = 4;
     const int GW_CHILD = 5;

    // GetWindowLong()
     const int GWL_EXSTYLE = (-20);
     const int GWL_STYLE = (-16);
     const int GWL_ID = (-12);
     const int GWL_HWNDPARENT = (-8);
     const int GWL_WNDPROC = (-4);

    // GetSysColor()
     const int COLOR_WINDOW = 5;
     const int COLOR_WINDOWTEXT = 8;

    // Mouse Key
     const int MK_LBUTTON = 0x0001;
     const int MK_RBUTTON = 0x0002;

    // Scrollbar
     const int SB_HORZ = 0;
     const int SB_VERT = 1;
     const int SB_CTL = 2;
     const int SB_LINEUP = 0;
     const int SB_LINELEFT = 0;
     const int SB_LINEDOWN = 1;
     const int SB_LINERIGHT = 1;
     const int SB_PAGEUP = 2;
     const int SB_PAGELEFT = 2;
     const int SB_PAGEDOWN = 3;
     const int SB_PAGERIGHT = 3;
     const int SB_THUMBPOSITION = 4;
     const int SB_THUMBTRACK = 5;
     const int SB_LEFT = 6;
     const int SB_RIGHT = 7;
     const int SB_ENDSCROLL = 8;
     const int SB_TOP = 6;
     const int SB_BOTTOM = 7;

     const int SORT_DEFAULT = 0x0;
     const int SUBLANG_DEFAULT = 0x01;

     const int SC_TASKLIST = 0xF130;

    // ShowWindow()
     const int SW_HIDE = 0;
     const int SW_NORMAL = 1;
     const int SW_SHOWMINIMIZED = 2;
     const int SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3;
     const int SW_MAXIMIZE = 3;
     const int SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE = 4;
     const int SW_SHOW = 5;
     const int SW_MINIMIZE = 6;
     const int SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE = 7;
     const int SW_SHOWNA = 8;
     const int SW_RESTORE = 9;
     const int SW_MAX = 10;

     const int SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
     const int SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
     const int SWP_NOZORDER = 0x0004;
     const int SWP_NOACTIVATE = 0x0010;
     const int SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040;
     const int SWP_HIDEWINDOW = 0x0080;
     const int SWP_DRAWFRAME = 0x0020;

    // System Metrics
     const int SM_CXSCREEN = 0;
     const int SM_CYSCREEN = 1;
     const int SM_CXVSCROLL = 2;
     const int SM_CYHSCROLL = 3;
     const int SM_CYCAPTION = 4;
     const int SM_CXBORDER = 5;
     const int SM_CYBORDER = 6;
     const int SM_CYVTHUMB = 9;
     const int SM_CXHTHUMB = 10;
     const int SM_CXICON = 11;
     const int SM_CYICON = 12;
     const int SM_CXCURSOR = 13;
     const int SM_CYCURSOR = 14;
     const int SM_CYMENU = 15;
     const int SM_CYKANJIWINDOW = 18;
     const int SM_MOUSEPRESENT = 19;
     const int SM_CYVSCROLL = 20;
     const int SM_CXHSCROLL = 21;
     const int SM_DEBUG = 22;
     const int SM_SWAPBUTTON = 23;
     const int SM_CXMIN = 28;
     const int SM_CYMIN = 29;
     const int SM_CXSIZE = 30;
     const int SM_CYSIZE = 31;
     const int SM_CXFRAME = 32;
     const int SM_CYFRAME = 33;
     const int SM_CXMINTRACK = 34;
     const int SM_CYMINTRACK = 35;
     const int SM_CXDOUBLECLK = 36;
     const int SM_CYDOUBLECLK = 37;
     const int SM_CXICONSPACING = 38;
     const int SM_CYICONSPACING = 39;
     const int SM_MENUDROPALIGNMENT = 40;
     const int SM_PENWINDOWS = 41;
     const int SM_DBCSENABLED = 42;
     const int SM_CMOUSEBUTTONS = 43;
     const int SM_CXFIXEDFRAME = 7;
     const int SM_CYFIXEDFRAME = 8;
     const int SM_SECURE = 44;
     const int SM_CXEDGE = 45;
     const int SM_CYEDGE = 46;
     const int SM_CXMINSPACING = 47;
     const int SM_CYMINSPACING = 48;
     const int SM_CXSMICON = 49;
     const int SM_CYSMICON = 50;
     const int SM_CYSMCAPTION = 51;
     const int SM_CXSMSIZE = 52;
     const int SM_CYSMSIZE = 53;
     const int SM_CXMENUSIZE = 54;
     const int SM_CYMENUSIZE = 55;
     const int SM_ARRANGE = 56;
     const int SM_CXMINIMIZED = 57;
     const int SM_CYMINIMIZED = 58;
     const int SM_CXMAXTRACK = 59;
     const int SM_CYMAXTRACK = 60;
     const int SM_CXMAXIMIZED = 61;
     const int SM_CYMAXIMIZED = 62;
     const int SM_NETWORK = 63;
     const int SM_CLEANBOOT = 67;
     const int SM_CXDRAG = 68;
     const int SM_CYDRAG = 69;
     const int SM_SHOWSOUNDS = 70;
     const int SM_CXMENUCHECK = 71;
     const int SM_CYMENUCHECK = 72;
     const int SM_MIDEASTENABLED = 74;
     const int SM_MOUSEWHEELPRESENT = 75;
     const int SM_XVIRTUALSCREEN = 76;
    // Stock Logical Objects
     const int SYSTEM_FONT = 13;        

     const int SM_YVIRTUALSCREEN = 77;
     const int SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN = 78;
     const int SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN = 79;

    // Virtal Keys
     const int VK_TAB = 0x09;
     const int VK_RETURN = 0x0D;
     const int VK_ESCAPE = 0x1B;
     const int VK_PRIOR = 0x21;
     const int VK_NEXT = 0x22;
     const int VK_F4 = 0x73;

     const int MAX_PATH = 260;

     const int MDITILE_VERTICAL = 0x0000;
     const int MDITILE_HORIZONTAL = 0x0001;
     const int MDITILE_SKIPDISABLED = 0x0002;

     const int S_OK = 0x00000000;
     const int S_FALSE = 0x00000001;
```